# Indexes of prime Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

I found this on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciPrime.html), but I can't seem to find any proof, either on StackExchange, nor any other site:

Why do all Fibonacci primes, except for $F_4=3$, have prime indexes (with $F_0=0$)?

My first thought was that necessarily, $F_{ab}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ would divide a previous Fibonacci number. And this seems to be actually true, one can experimentally show the first few cases work: $F_6=8$ divides $F_3=2$, $F_{10}=55$ divides $F_{5}=5$, and so on. So I immediately conjectured that for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $F_{a}\vert F_{ab}$.

Now, here is the thing. One can show by induction on $k$ that $F_n=F_{k+1}F_{n-k}+F_{k}F_{n-k-1}$ for $n, k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}_{0}$. This implies that if either a or b (let's say b WLOG) is a multiple of 2 ($b=2c$), by the above equation with $k=ac$ we get:$$F_{ab}=F_{2ac}=F_{ac+1}F_{ac}+F_{ac}F_{ac-1}=F_{ac}(F_{ac+1}+F_{ac-1})$$

But this just sets this for the even cases, and the odd cases should work too. So, how could I finish the proof?

Comment: It seems like your notation and usage for "$x$ divides $y$" is backwards compared to how most people do it. Also you have some typos with some parts of indices not being included in brackets in latex notation.

Comment: @user2566092 I've been kind of confused about the order of its usage for a very long time. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$F_{3n}=F_{n+1}F_{2n}+F_nF_{2n-1}$$
You already know $F_{2n}$ is a multiple of $F_n$ so...

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: This shows $F_{3n}$ is divisible by $F_n$, but OP might need a little more help to show that in general, $F_{kn}$ is divisible by $F_n$ for arbitrary $k > 1$. Or maybe not.

Comment: @user2566092 It's actually very clear how to proceed with induction with what Michael did... But that may need to be explained a little bit more.

Comment: @AnonymousPi I was just saying maybe induction needed to be mentioned, but since you accepted the answer I guess it's a non-issue. =)

Answer (score 2):

The Fibonacci have the following simple property:

If $m |n$ then $F_m | F_n$.

This property implies your claim.