# Index of Fibonacci primes and Lucas primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

For an integer $n\geq 0$ let $F_n$ denote the $n$th Fibonacci number and let
$L_n$ denote the $n$th Lucas number.

[It is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380396/indexes-of-prime-fibonacci-numbers)
that $F_n$ is prime only if $n$ is prime or $n=4$.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Lucas_primes)
it is known that $L_n$ is prime only if $n$ is $0$, prime or a power of $2$.

The reciprocals are not true. Indeed,
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
F_2    &= &1,\\
F_{19} &= &37\times 113,\\
L_{23} &= &139\times 461,\\
L_{64} &= &1087 \times 4481.
\end{array}$$

Let $S=\{n: F_n\text{ is prime}\}$ and $T=\{n: L_n\text{ is prime}\}$.

**Q**: Is the set $S\cap T$ finite?

**Some remarks:**

1. Some computations in Mathematica suggest that $n=4, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 47$ are all the integers in 
   $S\cap T$ with $n\leq 10000$.
2. It follows by the exposition above that an element of $S\cap T$ is either $4$ or prime.
3. It is not known whether there are infinitely many Fibonacci prime numbers. So, either my question is an open problem or the answer is yes.
4. My interest in the set $S\cap T$ arises from a question related to 
   giving approximations of $\sqrt{5}$ as the fraction of two prime numbers. [Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_numbers) that $\frac{L_n}{F_n}$ tends to $\sqrt 5$ when $n$ tends to infiniy.
5. I have no strong background on Fibonacci numbers. All remarks are welcome.

Comment: (1). I dk...(2). It is also not known whether $T$ is finite or not...(3). Since $F_{2n}=F_nL_n $ we have $n\in S\cap T$ iff $F_{2n}$ is the product of two primes.

Comment: OEIS [A080327](http://oeis.org/A080327) is the related sequence and indicates that the next, and conjectured only other, member of $S\cap T$ is $148091$. This in turn links to [Prime Curio](https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php?number_id=3994) which remarks on the precision of the related $L_n/F_n$ approximation to $\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question may not yet be answerable because we don't know if there exist an infinite number of Fibonacci (or Lucas primes); Moreover, we don't even know if there exist an infinite number of composite Fibonacci (Lucas) numbers.

One thing (among many) that we do know is that $F_{2n} = F_{n}L_{n}$ with the $gcd(F_{n}, L_{n})$ being either 1 or 2.